# Unknown word from Css Minimizer Plugin

Tags: javascript, css, webpack

I am trying to learn how to minimize javascript and css file using webpack for a project I am working on, but I keep getting the `Unknown word` Error from Css Minimizer Plugin every time. My css isn't complex, there's no special variables, or scss or less, or anything else. I just want to minimize the css for load time, but can't seem to figure it out.

I have searched online, on stack overflow and can't find anything that would make sense in my scenario. My webpack is pretty simple, and my css is pretty simple, but it fails on 1:10 every single time.

Here is my webpack.config.js...

```
const path = require("path");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const CSSMinimizerPlugin = require('css-minimizer-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    "myjsfile.js": './src/myjsfile.js',
    "myjsfile.min.js": './src/myjsfile.js',
    "mycssfile.min.css": './src/mycssfile.css'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name]'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /.css$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"]
      }
    ]
  },
  mode: 'production',
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [new CSSMinimizerPlugin()]
  },
  plugins: [new MiniCssExtractPlugin()]
}
```

I got pretty much all of that from the documentation on webpack here... https://webpack.js.org/plugins/css-minimizer-webpack-plugin/#examples

My css is extremely simple. I'll provide the line that is failing, which is line 1...

my mycssfile.css...

```
    @keyframes rotate-loading {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
        ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
        ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes rotate-loading {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
        ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
        ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate-loading {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
        ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
        ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@-o-keyframes rotate-loading {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
        ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
        ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes loading-text-opacity {
    0% {opacity: 0}
    20% { opacity: 0}
    50% {opacity: 1}
    100% {opacity: 0}
}
@-moz-keyframes loading-text-opacity {
    0% {opacity: 0}
    20% { opacity: 0}
    50% {opacity: 1}
    100% {opacity: 0}
}
@-webkit-keyframes loading-text-opacity {
    0% {opacity: 0}
    20% { opacity: 0}
    50% {opacity: 1}
    100% {opacity: 0}
}
@-o-keyframes loading-text-opacity {
    0% {opacity: 0}
    20% { opacity: 0}
    50% {opacity: 1}
    100% {opacity: 0}
}
.chat-loader,
.loading {
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    top: 25%;
    left: 25%;
}
```

That is the line that is failing according to the terminal error...

```
ERROR in mycssfile.css
mycssfile.css from Css Minimizer plugin
[path to file ommitted]/mycssfile.css:1:10: Unknown word [mycssfile.css:1,10]
```

I have no idea why it's failing. Honetly I am completely new to webpack, but it seems like a pretty simple thing, just minimize js and css files. I apologize for the long post, if any more information is needed please let me know and I will post it up. Thank you.

Comment: Can you put few extra lines of code after that line in your qus?

Comment: Added the first 100 lines of the css file that is causing the error.

Comment: @NeglectedSanity having the same issue.  Did you find a resolution?

Comment: @PaulFabbroni Kind of, but not really. I ended up removing the css minimizer plugin and instead just importing the css file into my javascript file, then by using the style-loader in webpack it adds the css to head tag in the final html when the page loads. It's not perfect because it doesn't minify the css, but it worked.

Comment: @NeglectedSanity in my case I was using tailwind and resolved my issue by following the tips found here https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode#arbitrary-value-support